# "come on as" versus "come across as"

Tags: idioms, word-usage, phrasal-verbs, dictionaries, phrase-usage

Would you say that both sentences sound correct?

1. On the whole, I think you came ON as sincere and credible, and your soft-spoken demeanor, laced with a dash of wry humor, was quite charming.
2. On the whole, I think you came ACROSS as sincere and credible, and your soft-spoken demeanor, laced with a dash of wry humor, was quite charming.

The McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs seems to suggest that both phrasal verbs are synonyms:

a. come on as something:
to appear to be something; to project one's image as something. (The senator comes on as a liberal, but we all know better. He comes on as a happy guy, but he is miserable.)

b. come across like someone or something (to someone)and come across as someone or something (to someone):
to appear or seem like someone or something to other people. (You always come across like a madman to people. She comes across like the Queen of the Nile to most people who meet her.)

Your thoughts? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd say that 'come across as' is much the more common in the UK.

Comment: Although I agree with their definition of "comes on as"; it's a bit old-fashioned. I haven't heard it in conversation ever, nor read it in anything written after maybe 1940.

Comment: So does the first sentence jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the noted synonymous definitions, I think the tell in these phrases is is often one of connotation. A *come-on*, through other uses, often connotes a sinister or self-serving action or a pretence.

*"You come on as if you own the joint."*

*"Did you come on to my sister?"*

To "*come off (as if)...*" is also used when appropriate (not in the second example ;-) and carries a similar connotation. On the other hand, "Came across as," while not unused in a derogatory sense, doesn't usually receive that immediate inference of a con job.

Comment: So would you say that the first sentece is wrong?

Comment: No, not wrong -- just a little more gentle in its connotation.

Comment: Did you mean the SECOND one comes across as more gentle?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with The McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs, the two phrases are indeed synonymous. Although I would break up your example sentences into more than one sentence, each.

Comment: Thank you, Mike. I felt that breaking up the sentences would make them sound choppy. I guess you aren't a fan of compound sentences. :-)

Comment: I don't mind compound sentences, but it just seems a bit cluttered and overwhelming in this instance. Though, technically speaking, I suppose it's fine.  =)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say they are synonymous.

In my opinion, *come on as* implies the person was actively trying to project a particular image. *Come across as* simply describes how he was perceived by others, maybe without him intending to do so.

From your quoted definition:

> come on as something: to appear to be something; **to project one's image as something.**